# How does StackExchange recognize me every time I browse here?

Tags: support

I use firefox (mainly on linux but also on windows), and I have it set up to delete cookies and browsing history every time I exit.  Despite this, every time I come to tex.stackexchange.com, I am recognized a few seconds after I connect.  How is this done without cookies?

Comment: Do you log in to a different SX site before you come to TeX.SX?

Comment: No, it happens even if I come here first.  In case it matters: I never actually log out, I just shutdown firefox.

Comment: How do you login? Using *Open Id* I assume? It could be some flash based cookie which isn't deleted by firefox.

Comment: Yes, I had to create one of those OpenId thingies to register, and I seriously don't understand what that is.  I've heard the phrase "flash cookie", but don't know what that is either.

Comment: I googled "flash cookies" and went to a macromedia web site that allowed me to delete all flash cookies from all sites.  I then shut down firefox, started up firefox, came here, and I was still recognized.  Weird...

Comment: Actually, this should probably be asked on meta.stackoverflow.com. Why isn't there a migration path to meta.SO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Traditional browser cookies [are by no means the only way to store tracking information](http://arstechnica.com/web/news/2010/09/evercookie-escalates-the-zombie-cookie-war-by-raising-awareness.ars). For example there are also cookies stored using Adobe Flash (use [this site to configure flash storage](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager07.html)).

EDIT: My original guess turns out to be wrong. They seem to use HTML5 local storage, as [described in a blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/). One way to somewhat reliably remove tracking information is the [BetterPrivacy Firefox addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/betterprivacy/) (I haven't tested that extensively, but it seems to work for stackexchange).

Comment: I already use noscript, so I tried blocking quantserve and google-analytics, shut down firefox, restarted firefox, came here, and it still recognized me.  I'm starting to think there's someone hiding in my closet.

Comment: @Phil: interestingly it does that for me now too. Anyway, as I said there are lots of methods for tracking users.

Comment: Aha: Private Browsing.  I started firefox, started private browsing, and I was not recognized here.  When I turned off private browsing and returned here, I was recognized.  I still wonder what's being stored where...

Comment: @Phil: see updated answer.

Comment: @Caramdir: Lovely!  Thanks very much.

Comment: @Phil, @Caramdir, from http://diveintohtml5.org/storage.html: Unlike cookies, this data is never transmitted to the remote web server (unless you go out of your way to send it manually).

Comment: @Hendrik: As long as the website can access it with javascript, it can send it to any place it likes.

Comment: @Caramdir: So you're saying the info at that link is misleading (or plain wrong)?

Comment: @Hendrik: it says '[html5 local storage] isn’t transmitted to the server', meaning that unlike a cookie it isn't sent to the server on every request. However, it must be accessible with javascript (otherwise it would be pretty useless) and it is possible to make arbitrary requests to the server using javascript (a feature that is used extensively in 'web2.0' sites). So there is nothing preventing the javascript on the site calling `example.com/tracker?id=<id from local storage>`.

Comment: Chrome's Incognito mode by default wipes all state at session end, including HTML5 local storage.

Comment: @Caramdir: Thanks for expanding. However, I'm still puzzled. Why on earth do they say "Unlike cookies, this data is _never_ transmitted to the remote web server (unless you _go out of your way_ to send it manually)"? I start tending to "plain wrong" ...

Comment: @hendrik: it is correct from the developer point of view.